# Window Authentication Using Node JS on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, active-directory, nodes, node-modules

I have multiple apps on Linux server. I want to use Window Authentication for login in apps. How can I do it using on Linux. I already Have connection with Active Directory. I just need current username of requested user for getting user profile from active directory.

Can I do it without deploying apps on IISNODE ???
I want on Linux. Is there any module available for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) (simpler, but older and apparently less secure) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) (the new way and more secure, but a little more complicated to setup).

There is a Kerberos module for Node, but I have no experience with it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos

Search for "[kerberos nodejs](https://www.google.com/search?q=kerberos%20nodejs)" and you should find more help.

I also found these walk-throughs to install modules on Apache to do it, in case they're helpful:

NTLM: http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/

Kerberos: https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Networking/Single_Sign_On/Kerberos_SSO_with_Apache_on_Linux.html